# land with and without a water source

Tags: word-request

What words can I use to distinguish between a land-plot that has a water source (e.g. well, spring, oasis...) and a land-plot that doesn't?

I thought of wet vs. dry, but these seem too general, not specific to lands.

I thought of fertile vs. infertile, but these are not specific to water.

Comment: Good question. Maybe there are specific terms for land with and/or without a water source - but if so, I doubt they're particularly common. Usually, the fact that there may be a water source isn't really critical though - what matters is whether it's [land with water **rights**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22land+with+water+rights%22&oq=%22land+with+water+rights%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.24740164j0j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Even if you have a well, that's no good if your neighbour extracts so much water the water table drops and your well runs dry.

Comment: Somewhat related: A country without access to the seas is called [landlocked country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_country), and a region where the precipitation is less than the evaporation is called [arid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arid), but in both cases there could be water sources.

Comment: There may be specific terms that I am not aware of, but I think what you have said in your opening sentence ("has a water source" vs. "does not have a water source") may be the best way to say it. As a parallel example, the word _fenestrated_ means "having windows," but 98% of the time, most folks are better off just saying, "I like how the windows are set up in this room" as opposed to, "I like how this room is fenestrated." Just because there **is** a word doesn't mean it's always best to use that word. Interesting question, though.

Comment: There isn't any confusion in your question, but with your second paragraph, be aware that "[wetland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetland)" has a specific meaning and usage that is NOT antithetical to "dry land". The same is true of [defenestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestration), although I suspect @J.R. chose it for humour value more than anything else.

Comment: @Stephen: arid sounds like a pretty good answer (although not exact). What would you consider a good antonym? humid? damp? moist?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: The antonym would be humid, cf. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Klimate-humidit%C3%A4t.png Look at Egypt: the climate there is arid, but the Nile river is a source of water, thus arid-humid is not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it is close enough.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: OK, I posted it as (lengthy) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A region with less [precipitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precipitation) than [potential evapotranspiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_evapotranspiration) is called [arid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arid) (from Latin *aridus*: dry, drouthy). This does not necessarily mean that there are no water sources. For example, when looking at [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Klimate-humidität.png](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aKlimate-humidit%C3%A4t.png) it can be seen that Egypt is arid, but of course there is the river Nile as source of water.

The antonym of arid is humid (cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humid#Climate).

When talking about availability of water, also [water rights](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22land%20with%20water%20rights%22&oq=%22land%20with%20water%20rights%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.24740164j0j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) must be taken into account, as pointed out by FumbleFingers. Additionally it might be necessary to distinguish between water and drinking water: think of an island in the ocean – lots of salt water, but maybe no fresh water.

A country without access to the seas is called [landlocked country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlocked_country), which is important when considering for example [ship transport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_transport) or [fishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing).

Note that a [wetland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetland) is not just wet land and that *irrigable* means *can be irrigated*. If you get water from somewhere (e.g. by pipeline), you could also irrigate an arid area, i.e. there exists *arid irrigable land*. *arid* and *irrigable* are not antonyms. [Irrigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrigation) is even applied to land which needs water, thus arid land gets irrigation but humid land will be seldom irrigated.

Merk mentioned http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_scarcity for additional thematic information. Also [FAO: The arid environments](http://www.fao.org/docrep/t0122e/t0122e03.htm) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

Lands with water security/sufficiency vs. lands with water scarcity/stress (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_scarcity)

Arid lands vs. irrigable lands

Lands with/without/starved of water resources

Comment: I wanted a single word or an adjective... *arid* vs. *irrigable* sounds like a good pair.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: _irrigable_ means _can be irrigated_, and when you get water from somewhere (e.g. by pipeline), you could also irrigate an arid area, i.e. there is _arid irrigable land_. They are not antonyms.